# Cross-reference multiple many-to-many relationships. Which database should I pick?

Tags: database, architecture, nosql, neo4j, google-cloud-datastore

I'm going to build a platform for online content.
This system will basically have two entitities: Content and Tag.
Tags are related to contents in a many-to-many fashion.

If I use a SQL database, it would be modeled like:

CONTENT 1-----* TC *-----1 TAG

Given this model, I need to make queries like:

1) Get content by id

2) Get content by one tag - "List all MATH* contents"

(*) MATH is a tag

3) Get content by multiple tags - "List all HARD* MATH* contents"

4) Filter the data above by Content attributes: - "List all HARD* MATH* contents that were created last week"

1 and 2 are hardly a problem, but I believe 3 and 4 can get tricky.

In a relational world, for query (4), I could start from CONTENT and join with TC multiple times, like so:

```
select distinct(c.*) from CONTENT c, TC tc1, TC tc2
where tc1.content_id = c.id
and tc2.content_id = c.id
and tc1.id = <math_tag_id>
and tc2.id = <hard_tag_id>
and c.creation_date > <last_week>
```

But I'm not sure this would scale well when:
    - TC has a lot of data
    - I need to query the intersection of 4 to 8 tags

**Any thoughts on this?**

In the noSQL world, the only database I worked with so far is BigTable.
As far as I can tell, BigTable might not be the best choice for this problem.
If I use the same "tables", for (3) I'd probably go with something like (assume ndb+python)

```
tcs = TC.query(
    TC.tag_key.IN([math_tag_key, hard_tag_key])
).fetch()
content_keys = [tc.content_key for tc in tcs]
distinct_content_keys = set(content_keys) //eliminate repeated values
contents = ndb.get_multi(distinct_content_keys)
```

But,

- I don't know how well this would perform when `TC.tag_key.IN` receives 4 to 8 tags (**any thoughts on this?**)
- I can't make query (4) because I can't join with CONTENT (BigTable doesn't do joins). The alternative would be replicating CONTENT's attributes in TC, which is a PITA. (**is there a better way to do this in BigTable?**)

So, the bigger question here is: what database solves this problem best?
I'm inclined to look into Graph databases to see how well they might solve this, but I think I need some expert opinions about it.

A Graph DB is really the way to go?
Is Neo4J the best option?

Comment: Another type of 'engine' you havent considered is a 'Full-Text' Search engine. Of which there are many, including one in GAE, but also Lucene, SphinxSearch etc. These are typically pretty good at these types of query (better than a database!). You store the original data in what ever database (DataStore/NoSql/RDMS whatever) but run queries in the search engine (which can usually get the data what ever the format).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the areas that graph databases excel at compared to relational DBs is the kind of problem you describe. If the answer in a relational DB world results in many joins (where many can depend on the DB, but starts to be an issue at maybe 8 and certainly by 16) then you should look at a graph DB.

In addition to Neo4J you may want to look at Titan and either way you may want to look at whether you want something like Blueprints or Spring on top to help isolate you from the implementation specifics (though that can bring other problems if you really need high performance).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Graphs really seem like the way to go. There's also another more specific question about Neo4j that may be of interest to readers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964315/beginner-in-cypher-list-actors-that-acted-in-all-3-matrix-movies