# Beginner in Cypher: List actors that acted in all 3 Matrix movies

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I started learning Neo4j last friday.

I've completed the [Cypher examples](http://www.neo4j.org/learn/cypher) on my local database, are there are some additional queries that I'd like to learn how to ask:

Given the three matrix movies, how do I list only actors that acted in all three of them?
Or more generally, suppose I have a bunch of movies, actors and ACTS_IN relationships.

Given 3 movies:

- List all the actors that acted in ALL 3
- List all the actors that acted in any of those 3 movies (and which movies they acted in)

Likewise, given 3 actors

- List all movies that have all 3 actors
- List all movies that have any one of those 3 actors (and which actors they have)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

acted in all 3:

```
start m1=node:node_auto_index(title="The Matrix"),
      m2=node:node_auto_index(title="The Matrix Reloaded"),
      m3=node:node_auto_index(title="The Matrix Revolutions")
match a-[:ACTS_IN]->m1, a-[:ACTS_IN]->m2, a-[:ACTS_IN]->m3
return a;
```

acted in any: (easiest syntax is the union only from 2.0, so I'm going to go with that)

```
start m=node:node_auto_index(title="The Matrix")
match a-[:ACTS_IN]->m
return a, m
union
start m=node:node_auto_index(title="The Matrix Reloaded")
match a-[:ACTS_IN]->m
return a, m
union
start m=node:node_auto_index(title="The Matrix Revolutions")
match a-[:ACTS_IN]->m
return a, m;
```

And they're basically the same for the other two queries, just switch title for name, and put the people's names, and swap m for a in the start clause. :)

Comment: alternative to UNION, you can use optional relationships.

Comment: (acted in any)
this would work too, right? 
 `START 
  m = node:node_auto_index('id:603 OR id:604 OR id:605')
 MATCH
  a-[:ACTS_IN]->m
 RETURN
  a.name, collect(m.title);` (Since I'm using 1.9.3)

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. Shorter syntax: `node_auto_index('id:(603, 604, 605)')`

Comment: This should be a "Cool stuff you can do with a Movie dataset" graphgist at gist.neo4j.org @WesFreeman .